# Filter by date using SQL

Tags: sql

I would like to know what do you think:

I have to get all the connections I had to the system during a session. To automatize this process, I decided to use current_date%, which won't work because current_date is not a string, it's a function.

So my question is if anyone can help me with the query to get the number of all the connections of the current day.

Thanks in advance!

My shitty code:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user_connections
WHERE connectiondate LIKE 'CURRENT_DATE%'
```

Comment: what is the type of the field, you are using for "connectiondate"

Comment: The data type is date, and the format saved in it, is this: 
2018-12-17T19:47:23.000Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way (from a performance perspective) is to use logic like this:

```
WHERE connectiondate >= CURRENT_DATE AND
      connectiondate < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 DAY'
```

Not all databases support ISO/ANSI standard syntax for dates, so the exact expression in your database may differ.

Answer (score 0):

You only need `connectiondate >= CURRENT_DATE`:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user_connections
WHERE connectiondate >= CURRENT_DATE
```

if the data type of `connectiondate` is `datetime`. 
If it is `date` then a simple `connectiondate = CURRENT_DATE` will do.

Comment: @MissCodesALot what happened?